# Why I need to click twice time on button to loading JS script by using jquery getscript with Laravel5.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a function to get Javascript from server when user click on a button by using Jquery getscript in Laravel5.0 the function work as well unless I click two time on that button at the first time.

**Issue:** For loading **model** I have to click on that button two times at the first time (Not double click mean that I have to click again and again) although my **javascript** loading with status:200 but **model** not work at the beginning and it will work after I click second times.

Here is my function

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info " data-toggle="modal" id="test" data-target="#create"> Create </button>
```

This is JS script for calling js files

```
@section('js')
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var url = "<?PHP echo url("js/libs.js");?>";

        $('#test').click(function () {

            var id = $(this).data("target").replace('#', '');
            $.getScript(url, function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {

                if (textStatus == 'success' && jqxhr.readyState == 4 && jqxhr.status == 200) {
                    myload({
                        id: id,
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

This is Javascript was called by Getscript

```
/**
 * Created by hengsoheak on 3/14/2016.
 */

function myload(id) {

    var data = '<div id="'+id.id+'" class="modal fade" role="dialog">';
    data += '<div class="modal-dialog">';

    data += '<div class="modal-content">';
    data += '<div class="modal-header">';
    data += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>';
    data += '<h4 class="modal-title"> Modal Header </h4>';
    data += '</div>';
    data += '<div class="modal-body">';
    data += '<p> Some text in the modal.</p>';
    data += '</div>';
    data += '<div class="modal-footer">';
    data += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>';
    data += '</div>';
    data += '</div>';
    data += '</div>';
    data += '</div>';

    $(data).appendTo("#result");

}
```

Finally I appendto a dive

```
<div id='result'></div>
```

This is result 
[image]

Comment: Any errors in console ?

Comment: As I the images and I have tried more time again and again but console status ok 200

Comment: Or it is work not good with Laravel token?

Comment: after I check in HTML on my #result at the first click my function already append html to it already but it not work seem Bootstrap not yet call Modal and aster I click second I see body and another Modal append or injected to html and send css too

Comment: You should be using `modal.show()` or something to make it appear I guess...

Comment: Ok I forgot it now working thanks

Comment: :P It was a _guess_! I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Comment: Oh @Rayon Dabre,
If I do like this is it good or not for security and performent ?

Comment: What is the point in creating `model` every time ?

Comment: because mostly of this application using Modal for edit,delete and check another task. so how it is good or not about performent

Comment: It is better to do minimum DOM manipulations if you do not have any other way around..

Comment: Oh so it will be slow right? as the above technique I used JS and dom too.

Comment: It will be slower but you may not experience it..But if it could be avoided then it should be avoided..